# ms-sql. Удалить лишние символы из строки

Tags: sql-server

Для удаления лишнего из строки в C# использую следующий способ

```
Regex.Replace("стро*ка с-о всякой вся"чиной", "[-., (){}@#$%^<>_?&*!+=№φ:;/\\[\\]]+", "")
```

Как тоже самое сделать на MS-SQL? Вариант replace(replace(i.str,'-',''),',','') и т.д, слишком длинный и не удобный.

Comment: Вот аналогичный вопрос на [EN_SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @charsToDelete nvarchar(200) = '-., (){}@#$%^<>_?&*!+=№φ:;/\';

-- Таблица с каждым символом @charsToDelete
DECLARE @charsTable TABLE
(value nvarchar(1) NOT NULL);

-- Заполняем таблицу @charsToDelete
INSERT INTO @charsTable
SELECT SUBSTRING(@charsToDelete, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ch), 1)
FROM (SELECT @charsToDelete ch) chars
INNER JOIN master..spt_values v ON v.number < LEN(@charsToDelete)
WHERE v.type = 'P'

DECLARE @destinationString nvarchar(4000) = 'стро*ка с-о всякой вся"чиной'

-- Заменяем каждый символ
SELECT @destinationString = REPLACE(@destinationString, value, '')
FROM @charsTable;

-- Выводим результат
SELECT @destinationString;
```

В случае с необходимости всё это можно это вынести в функцию.

Answer (score 2):

В MS SQL действительно нет полноценного аналога regex'ам из языков программирования.

Первый вариант - делать таблицу и цикл, как в соседнем ответе.

Второй вариант - труднее писать и поддерживать, но должно быть более оптимально с точки зрения производительности - писать монструозные конструкции типа replace((replace(@srting, '-', ''), '.', '') (это я для двух символов конструкцию написал, сами можете представить, какого она будет размера для 28 символов.

Третий вариант - подключение .net библиотек в качестве функций. Вариант опасен при использовании в промышленном окружении, т.к. потенциально может приводить к проблемам из-за утечек памяти, но позволяет использовать те же самые функции, что и в C#.
Пример использования и подключения библиотек дан, например, здесь: http://www.sql.ru/forum/1144247/faq-regex-parsim-zamenyaem-razbivaem-krutim-vertim

Answer (score 2):

Создаём функцию:

```
create function clean_string(@p varchar(255), @s varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
begin
  set @p = '%[' + @p + ']%';
  while patindex(@p, @s) > 0
    set @s = replace(@s, substring(@s, patindex(@p, @s), 1), '');
  return @s;
end;
```

Пример вызова функции: `select dbo.clean_string('аст', 'тестовая строка');`

Строка 'тестовая строка' будет очищена от символов 'а', 'с', 'т'.

Или вот это даже проще:

```
alter function [dbo].[clean_string](@p varchar(255), @s varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
begin
  while len(@p) > 0
    select 
      @s = replace(@s, left(@p, 1), ''), 
      @p = right(@p, len(@p)-1);
  return @s;
end;
```

Comment: Accolade! Отличное решение! работает и с спец-символами. Спасибо!